# How can I get back to Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The first time I went to the island of Pandaria, I did so via a quest in my faction capital (Orgrimmar/Stormwind).

If I leave Pandaria (by hearthing or some other method), how do I get back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Pandaren representatives are present in both faction capital cities, Orgrimmar and Stormwind, and are shown on the map for each city with the [image: icon] marker.

[image: Orgrimmar map]

[image: Stormwind map]

It is worth noting that as the faction cities on the island of Pandaria have a variety of portals leading to pretty much every major city in game (ie: Faction capital, Race capitals, Dalaran, Shattrah) that many people will probably be setting their hearthstones to an inn located on Pandaria rather than all congregating in the faction capitals.

Comment: To add onto the Faction capital portal note, you have to complete so many quests before the portal will actually appear. For example I had to go so far into the quest line in The Jade Forest until a portal to Stormwind was available in the first remote town.

Comment: Not sure on this - I did no quests in The Jade Forest, I did dungeons from 85-87 and then went to Kun Lai... It could be level related perhaps?

Comment: Phillip I am standing in front of the 2nd AH in the valley of honor right across from the Pandarian rep and I dont see the portal could you be a little more specific..thanks

Comment: @leety The portal to Stormwind in Paw'don Village is available as soon as you parachute down from the gunship.

Answer (score 3):

There is a portal in the Valley of Honor (where the 2nd AH and Bank is) to Pandaria for the Horde. There must be an equivalent in Stormwind. Can't check it myself atm but my guess would be somewhere in the Dwarven District.